# Selenium test hangs on css transition when chrome window is sent to background on mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium

I'm experiencing an annoying issue while running my behat selenium tests on my mac, El capitan.

I have a test that opens a modal that will hang if the chrome window is behind another window. As soon as I click on the chrome window to bring it to the front, the test continues and passes.

The modal uses a css transition to show. If I remove the transition, the test passes. If I keep a portion of the browser visible, the test passes.

I'm unsure if this is mac doing some kind of performance optimization or chrome. Anyone know of a way I can disable this? I'd rather not have to disable css transitions or run chrome headless.

Comment: What error do you get? driver timeout or that the element is not found? Have you tried with the latest versions of chromedriver and selenium?

Comment: The behat step that hangs is a "wait for modal to appear", which just checks if the modal element is visible. It retries for up to 30 seconds and then throws an exception. That is the exception that I get. I am using latest versions, selenium v2.53.1, chromedriver 2.24.

Comment: Make sure you wait for the page to be loaded. Try with selenium 3 also, make sure you specify the driver first, like:                                                java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that is not the reason. The assertion is in a loop that retries for 30 seconds, the page definitely loads, the modal element is found, the transition just does not complete. I'm pretty sure either mac or chrome is doing some kinds of performance optimization trickery.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows, so It is not only om mac.

Comment: This happens due to the way selenium works. It needs the chrome/element to be visible for the actions to work. I have seen some people who managed to fix this because they can multithread 100 browsers on top of each other and they all work. I still don't know how they do it though. If someone finds a solution please let as know. I currently move the window with a 10-pixel offset for each webdriver so they are all visible but this is really unstable...

Answer (score 1):

Here I found a [good article](https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0621889) and it helped me to find some flags for Chromium:
`--disable-renderer-backgrounding` — Prevent renderer process backgrounding when set.
`--disable-background-timer-throttling` — Disable task throttling of timer tasks from background pages.
`--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows` — Disable backgrounding renders for occluded windows. Done for tests to avoid nondeterministic behavior.

These flags really fixed the problem for me.

Some time ago I found mentioned and tried these flags `--disable-gpu` `--disable-d3d11`.
But they did not help.

More described flags can be found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).